# add Total to the duplicate values

Tags: reporting-services

I have requirement like

```
claimnumber   --  amount -- category    
-----------     ------  --------     
123     --         10  --    A   
123     --         10   --   B    
456     --         10   --   C    
456    --          10  --    B
```

I want report to group data like below,
distinct claim nos- 2
total charge for them is 20

```
Total Count  --  Total Amount
-----------    ------------   
2           --    20
```

How is it possible with ssrs.?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select 
count(claimnumber) as [total count],
sum(amount)        as [total amount] 
from tablename
group by claimnumber
```

Comment: i have to generate the second table based on first table(dataset) in ssrs report, not in sql.